# Is there a way to start from specific intent in google dialogflow?

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I'm using google dialogflow v2 API with java.

And I want to start my intent from specific position programmatically.

like

```
Intent A -> Intent B -> Intent C

Command : 'Start Intent from B'(Skip previous intents)
```

Is there a way to implement it or not?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since [Dialogflow](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/basics#api) is reliant on intents with training phrases.

> User interaction with the Dialogflow API:
>
> 1. The end-user types or speaks an expression.
> 2. Your service sends this end-user expression to Dialogflow in a detect intent request message.
> 3. Dialogflow sends a detect intent response message to your service. This message contains information about the matched intent, the
>    action, the parameters, and the response defined for the intent.

Thus whenever a user inputs a statement, dialogflow will check if it has an intent that was trained with regards to the user input and provide the appropriate response.